# Why does my smartObject in photoshop have content outside its Canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

When I pull in my .PSB into a new .PSD, for some reason it brings in content that sits outside the width / height of the Canvas.

I know I can fix this by creating a mask or cropping it out in the original .PSB, but is there a quicker way? I'm prototyping a background image size, and want it to be easy to go back and change it without having to do all these extra steps.

Thanks

Comment: Was wondering if it would be better to use layer comps to switch back & forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your smart object and save local drive. Use place command from file menu and select psb object. That will automatic re size as per your canvas. This command you can set in action also so you can use repeat.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding you correctly I would just use the crop tool and crop at your full canvas size. This will get rid of any layer elements outside the canvas bounds.